# PHP is it possible to extend a namespace to natively use functions outside of class

Tags: php, namespaces

Okay here is the scenario:

Here are two example classes.

1. The first one defines some functions outside the class name.
2. I would like the second class to be able to implement it as if it was defined natively.

There are a couple of functions I use a lot.

I thus need them to be as short as possible for readability and writing speed.

If i could stick them in a namespace and extend it in some way, it would also prevent possible conflicts in other libraries.

Base class

```
namespace Core;

class Base{
  ......
}

function set($array, $path=null, $value=null){
  .....
}

function get($array, $path=null){
  .....
}
```

Second Class

```
namespace Core\Config;

class Config{
  public function __construct($array){
    $conf = get($array, 'key1.key2.key3');
    .... do something with returned value ....
  }
}
```

Comment: Why.. not just declare them inside the `Base` class?

Comment: even if they are in the same class, you can call them without object

Comment: I can't seem to call functions outside of the class. Using the class works fine but no outside functions are calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone suffested that already but not in the right way:

```
<?php
namespace Base {
    function get() {...}
}

namespace Base\Config {
    use \Base as B;

    class Config {
        public function __construct(...) {
            $something = B\get(...);
        }
    }
}
```

You can import and alias the `Base` namespace and use it.
However, you cannot import a function or constant (only classes and interfaces)

Reference: [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

---

Also note, that you cannot *define a function in a class outside the class name*.
What you are doing is defining a class and several "stand-alone" functions in one file, but they do not relate in an way (they are in the same namespace, though).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you could use `functions` inside a class, even if they are in the same one without `$this->` or `$object->`. The solution I could provide very roughly is instantiating the Base class, if you are not able to extend it (a class named Base seems like one which should be extended, but anyaways):

```
namespace Core\Config;

class Config{

  private $_base;

  public function __construct($array){
    $this->_base = new Core\Base();
    $conf = $this->_base->get($array, 'key1.key2.key3');
```

---

Or, wrap them:

```
class Config {

    public function get($array, $path=null) {
        $base = new Core\Base();
        return $base->get($array, $path);
    }

    public function __construct($array) {
        $conf = $this->get($array, 'key1.key2.key3');
    }
```

---

OK, Now I see, they are functions in a file, which contains class.

```
namespace Core\Config;
use Core;
class Config {
    public function __construct($array) {
            $conf = Core\get($array, 'key1.key2.key3');
        }
```

Or for minimzing the work, you can alias gore `as C` for example

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose, the whole point is keeping the code as brief as possible. adding $this->_base-> is kind of what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @user787301  You know they are methods, not native functions, they are encapsulated into an object, and should be used from its instance. You cannot alias methods, but you can wrap them. Let me edit the answer

Comment: Look at the example again. The two functions shown are outside the class. the are not supposed to be methods.

Comment: I am trying to extend the base file in a way that non class functions can be used as if they were declared inside the current namespace.

Comment: @user787301  Aaah. So you need to use the namespace (or its alias) before the function name. Will edit once again.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think the answer below will fit my needs.